# Auto-increment a value after 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project where a field value need to auto-increment after every 1 minute. Is it possible to do it with MYSQL or PHP?

Comment: What did you try so far? Or is this only a question than just google it before you ask it

Comment: Which field need to auto increment?

Comment: Once or every one minute?`

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Every 1 minute. I already tried google, Still No solution found

Comment: can you help @Eakethet.?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd rather use the created timestamp than an error prone increment.

Comment: Where is your value? What is the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use a scheduled event within the database.

`CREATE EVENT [IF NOT EXIST]  event_name
ON SCHEDULE <schedule>
DO
<event_body>`

> First, you specify the event name after the  CREATE EVENT clause. The
>   event name must be unique within a database schema. Second, you put a
>   schedule after the  ON SCHEDULE clause. If the event is a one-time
>   event, you use the syntax:AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL] If the event is a
>   recurring event, you use the EVERY clause:EVERY interval STARTS
>   timestamp [+INTERVAL] ENDS timestamp [+INTERVAL] Third, you place the
>   SQL statements after the DO keyword. It is important to notice that
>   you can call a stored procedure inside the body of the event. In case
>   you have compound SQL statements, you can wrap them in a  BEGIN END
>   block.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/